# How to center only text in gridview?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Follow code:

**axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_chars"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:columnWidth="40dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Text is centered to the left. How do I center in the middle?

**Update:**

Here is the code in C #, as I add the letters below:

**C#:**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    string[] chars = new string[]
    {
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
        "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
        "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
    };
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_chars, container, false);
    GridView grid = (GridView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.grid_chars);
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, chars);

    grid.Adapter = adapter;

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Tried android:textAlignment="center" on your GridView?

Comment: Yes, it does not work.

Comment: Hi, @MatheusMiranda, have you tried my answer?

Comment: @VishvaDave I've seen your answer and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3ed7dba/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) is the `SimpleListItem1` layout source:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Here `android:gravity="center_vertical"`, this is why

> Text is centered to the left, not centered to the middle.

In your axml, the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` is just to tell the `GridView` to be center in the `RelativeLayout`. You need find the `GridView`'s item layout, and find the `TextView` to set its `gravity` to be center.

---

You need create a new layout named `item_layout`.

In  the `item_layout.xaml`, change `center_vertical` to `center`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

And then replace:

```
 ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, chars);
```

to:

```
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.item_layout, chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try :**

```
  android:gravity="center"
  android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
```

**OR**

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change layout of your item.If it's RelativeLayout,add code:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

If it's LinearLayout ,add this code:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

If it's just TextView ,add code:

```
 android:gravity="center"
```